# tools to help trace block being called during fb logout

Tags: objective-c-blocks, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm having a strange bug where a block from my login method is erronusly getting called again in the middle of my facebook signout function.  It's a lot of code to post, but my question is how can I debug in xcode.  Are there specific tools I can use to help trace where the block is being called from?

Here's the thread information

```
#0  0x0017ca21 in __46-[FacebookRepo startLoginWithCompletionBlock:]_block_invoke at /Users/transformer/Projects/PictoriousApp/Pictorious/Core/FacebookRepo.m:183
#1  0x00440a96 in -[FBSession transitionAndCallHandlerWithState:error:token:expirationDate:shouldCache:loginType:] at /Users/jacl/src/release-trashme/ios-sdk/src/FBSession.m:1497
#2  0x004414fa in -[FBSession closeAndClearTokenInformation:] at /Users/jacl/src/release-trashme/ios-sdk/src/FBSession.m:1702
#3  0x0043d814 in -[FBSession closeAndClearTokenInformation] at /Users/jacl/src/release-trashme/ios-sdk/src/FBSession.m:417
#4  0x0017d1c4 in -[FacebookRepo startLogout] at /Users/transformer/Projects/PictoriousApp/Pictorious/Core/FacebookRepo.m:248
#5  0x00198dad in -[PictoriousSession startLogout] at /Users/transformer/Projects/PictoriousApp/Pictorious/Core/PictoriousSession.m:140
#6  0x00212841 in -[EditProfileViewController userLogOut] at /Users/transformer/Projects/PictoriousApp/Pictorious/Controllers/People/Profile/EditProfileViewController.m:293
```

Makes it seem like

Answer (score 0):

I've stuck with the similar problem. In my case it happened when I call `closeAndClearTokenInformation` method.
I've solved this problem just creating new instance object of `FBSession` before calling this method.

```
self.session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
[self.session closeAndClearTokenInformation];
```

Hope it will help you.